# How to Install MySQLdb in PyCharm, Windows，python2.7

Tags: python, pycharm, mysql-python

I am new to Python(I am using Python2.7) and Pycharm, but I need to use MySQLdb module to complete my task.
I spent time to search for some guides or tips and finally I go to here but does not found MySQLdb to install. 
[MySQL-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhTaq.png)

But there is error：
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsXZi.png)

Answer (score 7):

I have a suggestion,if you have install MySQL database,you follow this,open pycharm and click File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter,then select your Python interpreter and click install button (the little green plus sign),input "MySQL-Python" and click the button "install package",you will install MySQL-Python successfully.If you have not install MySQL database,you need install MySQL database first.

Comment: In MacOs: PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpeter

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to install MySQL CLient in Pycharm, try opening the Terminal (Alt+F12) and write the command

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

This might help!

Comment: It says syntax error in PyCharm. `pip install --only-binary : all: mysqlclient
  File "<input>", line 1
    pip install --only-binary : all: mysqlclient
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Command Prompt / Linux Shell

install using wheel

```
pip install wheel
```

Download 32 or 64 Bit version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

**64-Bit**

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

**32-Bit**

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

**Using Anaconda2:**

Open a Command Prompt

```
$ conda install mysql-python
```

Press y to proceed with installation

Comment: I use python 2.7.11 in C:\Anaconda2\python.exe.But, follow your way,I can solve the problem in python in C:\Python27. But there is still error in C:\Anaconda2\python.exe

Comment: I updated my comment to include the Anaconda instructions.